# Joomla: Login links for "Forgot your password?" and "Forgot your username?" are broken, SEF related?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla1.6, joomla2.5

Got a fun new bug report this morning - the "Forgot your password?" and "Forgot your username?" generated links don't seem to be working.  I don't remember actually testing them so it's possible this has been this way for awhile.

This is a completely password protected site, so the login form is the only thing on the first page of the site (and using a separate stripped down template for just that page).  They work on my local version with SEF and URL rewriting off...so I'm pretty sure that has something to do with it but don't see anything out of the ordinary.  I've also never touched the .htaccess file that installs with Joomla with the exception of renaming it but thinking that has something to do with this since it's the only difference between the two versions.

**Local:** (working)

```
/index.php?option=com_users&view=reset
/index.php?option=com_users&view=remind
```

**Live:** ("index.php?options=com_users&" gone)

```
/?view=reset
/?view=remind
```

Also, (though since it's working locally I don't think this is it) I have a conditional in the head of the login page that redirects anyone with a userid to the main site, and if they don't have a userid then nothing happens.  Locally the forget your password/username links are winding up on a semi broken inner page template, not staying on the first page.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I had a second remote site, switched off SEF URLs and those links came back...but the site depends on them.  Anyone have suggestions on maybe an .htaccess exception?  Or other ideas?  Thanks!

**Edit 2**

Here's the .htaccess file:

```
##
# @version      $Id: htaccess.txt 20196 2011-01-09 02:40:25Z ian $
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2011 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/component/) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: Is there server a LAMP (Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP) server?

Answer (score 0):

few questions (sorry, can't seem to leave a comment on your post...):
Do you have any sef components enabled on the livesite?
How about your sef settings in your global config?
Have you set your htaccess.txt to .htaccess?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I don't have any SEF components except for the Joomla one.  htaccess.txt has been changed to .htaccess.  And these are the SEO settings: http://prntscr.com/7jjnf  ( y - y - y- n )

Comment: Okay, have you changed the any of the contents in the htaccess file in anyway? That screenshot you gave seems okay, so it's most likely the htaccess file...

Comment: Never touched any of it - I'll post it above.

Comment: Have you tried it after removing your conditional rule in the login page? It could also be something with your host too, so it's worth checking with them...

Comment: I thought about the conditional, tried removing that but no change.  Definitely has something to do with SEF.  Tried it on three different hosts too - same problem (also good thought!).

Answer (score 0):

The urls you have posted appear to be relative - ie they are not anchored at the root of your domain. With SEF turned on the 'apparent' urls of your pages are /somthing/something-else.html

A relative urls from this 'apparent' url will break.

The fix is to add a line to your configuration.php file (inside the class that is defined there) to force Joomla to show a  line to your pages. This will fix 'broken' relative urls.

```
var $live_site = 'http://www.your-domain.com';
```

Sorry - I can't recall off hand whether you need to put a slash at the end of the url - I think not, but perhaps suck it and see.

Comment: Thanks - little searching indicated no slash at the end (tried it a few different ways anyway) but it's still not working :/  Think we're on the right track though; is there anywhere else that this could be set?  One piece of info that's probably not important, the site is at 'http://your-domain.com' vs 'http://www.your-domain.com' (no www).  Can't see how that could make a difference but wanted to throw it out there.  Thanks!

Comment: [note to anyone who finds this thread - make sure to change permissions in your configuration.php back to 444; may need to go through your cPanel to do it]

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that this is not related to the htaccess file as all. I'd need a little more information to confirm that my suspicions are correct, so please do let me know if any assumptions are wrong.

I would guess that you have assigned the homepage of your site to a login menu type. To get the "forgot password?" and related links though, you likely also added the login module to the homepage (and possibly even hidden the component output for the homepage as part of stripping everything down.

Having the homepage as a menu type under the users component will cause Joomla's router to create the link as you specified since the router will first look for a menu item that matches the option and view and, not finding that, will find one that just matches on option, which in your case is the homepage (i.e. nothing is needed in the url). If your homepage was not a user menu type, you would get a url that has this: component/users/?view=remind.

Even with the user menu type for the homepage, the different pieces should still load in the component output on the homepage, so really you would just need to unhide the component output and you should see the information displayed.

Alternately, you could create new menu items that are available to the public (typically in their own menu) that contain an item for reset, remind, register. Then the links will be /reset instead of /?view=reset and it will go to this other page that should have the functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I tried unhiding the component, the links are there but still incorrect. I will try the menu link options a little later and report back.